# pyspark warnings when running on single node

Tags: pyspark

this is my first time running `pyspark` directly.  I am very familiar with Databricks using dataframe syntax.  The following code samples is working fine on a single Azure Compute Instance (this is just for inference on a large dataset, I do not need a multi-node setup).  Q: how do I get rid of the warnings shown below? (pyspark 3.4.1, openjdk version 20.x)

```
# %%
import os
import sys

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
#os.environ["SPARK_LOCAL_IP"] = "10.0.80.11"  

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

conf = (
  SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.memory.fraction", 0.8)
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "16g") 
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
    .set("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", False)
  )
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")


# %%
if __name__ == "__main__":
  sdf = spark.read.load("/mnt/azureblobshare/fact_code")
  sdf.groupby("code").agg(F.countDistinct("id").alias("nid")).show()
```

Warnings:

```
23/08/09 15:41:44 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ... resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.80.11 instead (on interface eth0)
23/08/09 15:41:44 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/08/09 15:41:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/08/09 15:41:45 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
[28.047s][warning][gc,alloc] Executor task launch worker for task 46.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 47): Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 8619915 words
...same Executor message 5 times...
```

I realize that if I uncomment the LOCAL_IP env, the first warning will go away.  But when I check this is and others run it, their IP will be different.  How do I change it so that each user does not need to change.